# Android intent tel: - Проблема с отображением

Tags: android, android-sdk

делаю переход с приложения Android с номером телефона для звонка в поддержку, но на выходе получаю номер следующего вида: 000/000 00 00; хотя передаю (0000000000) все слитно и без слеша. Такая проблема на одном только Redmi 9T. Может кто-то сталкивался и сможет дать совет что делать.) Пр этом всем прописать номер в таком виде у меня не получится вообще, так как при наборе нет не циферных символов кроме плюса.

```
val regex = """[^0-9+]+""".toRegex()
val phone = getString(R.string.val_support_number)
val str = "tel:${phone.replace(regex, "")}"
val date = Uri.parse(str)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).setData(date)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Возможно срабатывает маска ввода и это просто разделитель кода города у них такой? Если просто ввести эти цифры символ появляется? Я бы попробовал использовать номер с `+`.